# Plotting $f(x) = \sin(x)+\cos(x)$ by converting it to another form

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, graphing-functions

Are there any trigonometric identity that can make $f(x) = \sin(x)+\cos(x)$ easier to plot? I have no idea how it becomes a sin graph shape in the end.

Comment: Note that $\sin x+\cos x=\sqrt 2\left(\dfrac 1{\sqrt 2}\sin x+\dfrac 1{\sqrt 2}\cos x\right)=\sqrt 2\sin(x+\pi/4)$

Comment: How do you get the identity in the bracket? I can't seem to find it anywhere else. Where can I find other examples of such identities?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Special Case**

It's not that hard. You should just use the summation formula for sines:

$$\sin (x + y) = \sin (x)\cos (y) + \cos (x)\sin (y)$$

This is how it works

$$\eqalign{
   \sin (x) + \cos (x) &= \sqrt 2 \left( {{1 \over {\sqrt 2 }}\cos (x) + {1 \over {\sqrt 2 }}\sin (x)} \right)  \cr 
   &= \sqrt 2 \left( {\sin ({\pi  \over 4})\cos (x) + \cos ({\pi  \over 4})\sin (x)} \right)  \cr 
  &= \sqrt 2 \sin (x + {\pi  \over 4}) \cr} $$

That's all you need to do for this case. If you are interested to tackle down the general case then read the sequel.

---

**General Case**

Consider a linear combination of $\sin \alpha x$ and $\cos \alpha x$ as follows

$$y = A \cos \alpha x + B \sin \alpha x$$

where $A$ and $B$ are some real constants. Then we rewrite $y$ in this way

$$y = \sqrt{A^2+B^2} \left( \frac{A}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}} \cos \alpha x + \frac{B}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}} \sin \alpha x \right)$$

Now, the magic comes in! We can find a **unique** angle $\phi$ in the interval $[0,2\pi)$ such that

$$\begin{array}{}
\sin \phi = \dfrac{A}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}} \\
\cos \phi = \dfrac{B}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}
\end{array}$$

and hence

$$y = \sqrt{A^2+B^2} \left( \sin \phi \cos \alpha x + \cos \phi \sin \alpha x \right) \\$$

Finally, using the summation formula for sines we get

$$y = \sqrt{A^2+B^2} \sin(\alpha x+\phi)$$

Answer (score 1):

**Note** Using the formula for $\sin(A)+\sin(B)$ you get

$$\sin(x)+\cos(x)=\sin(x)+\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)=2\sin( \frac{x+\frac{\pi}{2}-x}{2}) \cos(\frac{x-\frac{\pi}{2}+x}{2})$$
which is easy to calculate and plot.

Note also that 
$$\cos(x- \frac{\pi}{4})=\cos(\frac{\pi}{4}-x)=\sin( \frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{4}+x)$$
which is consistent with the other answer.